# Display a SQLite colum one value after another

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I'm really strugling to figure this out and had not found an answer or a way to do it.

What I'm trying to do is having questions that are saved in a SQLite colum to be displayed in a TextView one after another until they finish.

What I have done so far on the main Activity

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        btn1star = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1star);
        btn2star = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2star);
        btn3star = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3star);
        mListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.qlistview);
        qTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qTextView);


        questionsListView();

    }

    private void questionsListView() {

        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        data.moveToFirst();
        qTextView.setText(data.getString(1));

    }


    public void VoteClick(View view){
        mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();

        if (data.getCount() >=1){


         for (int i = 0; i< data.getCount(); i++) {
             data.moveToNext();

         Log.i("Counted Questions are: ", String.valueOf(data.getCount()));
             qTextView.setText(data.getString(1));

         }


                }

            }



    private void toastmessage (String message){

        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }




}
```

I'm able to display the first and when i click the button the last question
I'm unable to display the questions between.

Any tip or suggestion?

Comment: Does this apply? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258975/sqlite-query-get-all-columns-of-a-rowandroid

Answer (score 0):

In your `VoteClick` method you do your `getReadableDatabase`, this is too late, move this line into `onCreate` method. You must open the database before reading from it (in `questionsListView`).

```
mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();//move to onCreate
```

add this:

```
  startManagingCursor(data);
  data.moveToFirst();
```

BEFORE the line:

```
if (data.getCount() >=1){
```

Comment: the app is crashing with this and the android studio pulls a line on startManaging and say its deprecated

Comment: It is ok that it is deprecated, you can still use it, it just means there there is a better way (using cursor loader), but that is harder to write.

Comment: You realize the for loop will whizz through the table and qTextView.setText will have no time delay to display all the values ? You will only see if it is working in Log.i("Counted Questions...

Comment: Try it without startManagingCursor.

Comment: Yeap your right just noticed that every time i click the button is display 6 times(which is the number of records) the count number..

Comment: if ( data.getPosition() <= data.getCount()){

            startManagingCursor(data);

             data.moveToNext();

             qTextView.setText(data.getString(1)); tryed that but its not working

Comment: Try it without startManagingCursor. "It's not working" is of no help to me.

Comment: i can see on the log that everytime i click the button now i get 1 count but the text dont change

Comment: still havent manage to make it work. ill search the cursor loader option... thank you for your fart reply though

Answer (score 0):

Hello found a solution to my problem

It turns out that i have to make a new int variable
Get its value from the first id
and incrise this by one at the end of each button press until i reach the last cursor place whhere i move the cursor to the first position

public void VoteClick(View view) {

```
  Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
  data.moveToPosition(q);
  data.moveToNext();
  qTextView.setText(data.getString(1));
  while (data.isLast()) {
      data.moveToFirst();
      q = data.getPosition();
  }
  q = q+1;
  }
```