# Sqlite query is yielding last but one row value instead of last inserted row value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, flutter, dart

I have a weird sqlite problem, partly Flutter partly Android... I have a database that I create in Flutter. When I insert a new row and I save it, I want to retrieve it in Android and send the values to a broadcast receiver. I am using this query: `"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + COLUMN_ID + " DESC LIMIT 1";` This works great when creating the first row, but after that my broadcast receiver only ever receives the value of the last but one row, not the last row.

This is my code on the Java side, to get the details from the sqlite database and send them to the receiver:

```
    public void getScheduleFromFlutter() {
        String setting = "";
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        Cursor cursor = db.getValues();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            setting = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SETTING));
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Schedules.class);
        intent.putExtra("SETTING", setting);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might have some issues in the query to retrieve the last row.

However if you re inserting values in table with [Sqflite](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite).

When inserting a value:

```
  // Insert the Dog into the correct table. You might also specify the
  // `conflictAlgorithm` to use in case the same dog is inserted twice.
  //
  // In this case, replace any previous data.
  await db.insert(
    'dogs',
    dog.toMap(),
    conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace,
  );
```

The method insert returns a future with the ID of new column.

```
  // INSERT helper
  Future<int> insert(String table, Map<String, dynamic> values,
      {String nullColumnHack, ConflictAlgorithm conflictAlgorithm});
```

You can then send this ID instead or query the table with  this ID to get the entry you need.

Comment: Thanks!  Hopefully your answer will help someone else. I used this answer and it worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17259017/5513788.